# Sharing to both Facebook and Twitter at same time

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, sharing

Is there a way to share to both Facebook and Twitter at the same time? It seems like bad form to display the facebook popup, have the user write their text, then after they submit open the Twitter popup.

edit: I am asking if this is possible using iOS 6 sharing framework, and if so how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to share to Facebook and Twitter at the same time. You have to first write text in the Facebook screen and then in the Twitter screen, or vice versa.

Maybe it is possible to write something in the Facebook screen, store it in a variable and use it with SLComposeViewControllers' setInitialText method.

Comment: Ok that's what I figured.. Thanks!